# How to sort DataGridView Column by date in VB visual studio 2012?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my DGV, I have date list in the column (1):

```
11-Sep-2014
11-May-2011
11-Jan-2014
11-Mar-2014
12-Sep-2010
```

how to get descending result like this:

```
11-Sep-2014
11-Mar-2014
11-Jan-2014
11-May-2011  
12-Sep-2010
```

The Column(1) is not DateTime type but SortText type, I must set string like that. Could it sorted?

I have tried using code:

```
DGV.Columns(1).SortMode = DGV.Sort(DGV.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

but it's useless, it don't sort by date :(

this is my DGV: [image]

Okeh, this is my DGV code in brief:

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class LapTransaksiSimpanan

```
Public Sub Koneksi()
    str = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=dbkoperasi.mdb"
    Conn = New OleDbConnection(str)
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Conn.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Sub TampilGrid()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from LapTransaksiSimpanan", Conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "LapTransaksiSimpanan")
    DGV.DataSource = ds.Tables("LapTransaksiSimpanan")

    'on the below I wanna to sort the column, my code below is useless :(
    DGV.Sort(DGV.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)

    DGV.Columns("ID_Simpanan").Width = 120
    DGV.Columns("NAK").Width = 37
    DGV.Columns("Tanggal").Width = 75
    DGV.Columns("Jumlah").Width = 110
End Sub

Private Sub Setoran_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call Koneksi()
    Call TampilGrid()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: how is your date column declared? Also, how are you getting this onto your form?

Comment: Is your date list a string list or actual type "date"? If it is a string, it will sort like it did in your DGV. You can fix it by changing your type in the column or creating a custom sort ICompare

Comment: Please show some code, specifically the binding part. If binding is to a data table, also include how this data table is populated.

Comment: My date list is string, but this is get from format date.
I must set The Tanggal column as string, how to sorted it?

Answer (score 1):

> **There's a difference between `storing` and `displaying` data.**

You need to change you database table schema. The `Tanggal` column should be of type `date` or `datetime`. When you've fixed this, it's trivial to display dates using a custom format:

```
Me.DGV.Columns("Tanggal").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```

If you for some reason cannot change the schema, then you need to create a custom comparer by implementing [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx). There's an example at the bottom of [this MSDN  page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim tnd As Date
    For Me.i = 0 To X1.RowCount - 2
        tnd = X1.Item(1, i).Value
        X1.Item(6, i).Value = tnd.ToOADate.ToString
    Next
```

X1 is DataGridView
Column 1 would have your date ex 5/4/1987 
Column 6 would be calculated as MS date number in integer and must be converted to string.
Make sure X1 grid is Sort enabled
Now simply click on Column 6 header to sort.
Hope that works.